# Joomla preg_replace dont work

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to delete multiple spaces.

It works good:

```
$test = array('bla bla   blaa   ', 'eee asdasd lorem mmmm    asdasd asdd   ss');
foreach($test as $item) {
  echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $item)."\n";
}
```

But when I make `Joomla 3.2` plugin, and I explode article content (new line),
it doesn't work, I don't know why.

```
$string = explode("\n", $text); // art content

foreach($string as $item) {
    echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $item)."\n"
}
```

**EDIT DEBUG:**

It doesn't work...

```
$string = explode("\n", $text);

foreach($string as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
    echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $item)."\n";
}
```

return

```
                    string(53) "<p>ballll asf           aikasifn     asf </p>
"
<p>ballll asf           aikasifn     asf </p> 
string(58) "<p>lorem          i   psdfaufma   asfasf</p> "
<p>lorem          i   psdfaufma   asfasf</p>
```

Comment: You probably miss the parameters. Try adding `//gi`.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s+/gi', ' ', $item)`. `gixsm` are all the parameters you can give. Google for their meaning :). You can also try to search for *2 or more* by using `/\s{2,}/` so you won't just replace single spaces.

Comment: I get error Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to mention that PHP doesn't support that tag. Preg-replace has that parameter by default.

Answer (score 0):

[RegExr example](http://regexr.com?37dt2)

You might want to use *2 or more* to correctly match the replacements.

```
echo preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', '', $item)."\n"
```

**UPDATE**

```
$text = <<<EOF
<p>ballll asf           aikasifn     asf </p>
<p>ballll asf           aikasifn     asf </p>
EOF;

$string = explode("\n", $text);

foreach($string as $item) {
    //var_dump($item);
    echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $item)."\n";
}
```

Produces:

```
macbook-pro:Desktop allendar$ php -f test.php 
<p>ballll asf aikasifn asf </p>
<p>ballll asf aikasifn asf </p>
```

Comment: The Regex isn't the problem then. You should try to debug step-by-step until you see what's going wrong. Native PHP functions should just act accordingly. If there are custom functions involved you might want to check if their results are correct (thus correctly processed).

Comment: Try to do a `print_r` or `var_dump` on that `$string` and maybe for debugging replace all `\n` with `___` to see if there really are line breaks. It might be something else.

Comment: Ok, but $text have a content from joomla

Comment: That shouldn't matter. A string is a string. There might be something shady in that content tho. Maybe weird foreign characters or placeholders like `\r \t` etc.

Comment: How can i remove multiple space, \r and \t ??

Comment: You can `OR` multiple strings to replace, like so; `\s+|\t+|\r+`

Comment: I can't help you if you don't do any effort to give back what you try. You obviously should understand that `Still don't work...` won't help solving your issue.